# Counting Results With IdiORM When An Array Is Returned

Tags: php, database, charts, idiorm

Currently my db stores emails and the date collected.  I want to build an chart that shows how many emails were collected each day.  I found a tutorial using idiORM but this graphs values that are returned from the db and not counting how many are returned.

Any ideas on how to count for each result?

```
if (isset($_GET['start']) AND isset($_GET['end'])) {

$start = $_GET['start'];
$end = $_GET['end'];
$data = array();

// Select the results with Idiorm
$results = ORM::for_table('tbl_data')
        ->where_gte('date', $start)
        ->where_lte('date', $end)
        ->order_by_desc('date')
        ->find_array();


// Build a new array with the data
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key]['label'] = $value['date'];
    $data[$key]['value'] = $value['email'];
}

echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Did you see [documentation](https://idiorm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/querying.html#counting-results)?